# Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "custom argument" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, syntax-error, apply

I created a data frame "logLik.dat" with one column "x" of a sequence between -3 and 3 by 0.1

```
x <- seq(-3, 3, by=0.1)
logLik.dat <- data.frame(x)
```

Now I want to create a new column "logLik1" by using the apply() function with my custom function:

```
log.likelihood <- function(x, mu, sigma.2) {
(1/(sigma.2*sqrt(2*pi)))*(exp(-(((x-mu)^2)/(2*sigma.2^2))))
}
log.likelihood(x, mu=0, sigma.2=1)
```

I am having trouble with my apply() syntax.

I've tried this.

```
logLik.dat$logLik1 <- apply(logLik.dat, 1, log.likelihood)
```

And I get this error.

Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "sigma.2" is missing, with no default

Comment: The error is telling you that you're missing arguments for your function. Try `apply(logLik.dat,1,log.likelihood,mu=1,sigma.2=1)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Chi Pak, it worked.